# Best practices for passing parameters to model

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular. Wondering about best practices.

I have a model which contains a function that calls an API with various parameters:

```
// search headlines
$scope.search = function(params) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET', 
        url: '/api/headlines',
        params: params
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.headlines = data.headlines;
        $scope.count = data.count;
        $scope.page = data.page;
        $scope.total_pages = data.total_pages;
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.err = true;
    });
};
```

In my view, I would like to do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="headline in headlines" class="headline">
    <a href="" ng-click="search({ author: headline.author })">{{headline.author}}</a>
</div>
```

So the user can search by author only. Note that the API params may be any of `{q, page, author, category, ...}` and different parameters are relevant to different searches.

What is the best practice for sending parameters to the model and binding them to an anchor as above?

Thanks!

Comment: That seems fine to me. You could of course provide further levels of abstraction so as to not complicate the view, such as `searchByAuthor()`, but depending on your scenario that might be an overkill. I would, however, put all this $http logic into a separate service.